# Alfresco share form id element not working

Tags: alfresco-share

I have following in share-config. without id it works fine. 
after I added id attribute the form is not dispalyed. error is -
A form could not be found, has an 'itemKind' and 'itemId' been provided?

```
<config evaluator="task-type" condition="reimbursement:benefitAndEnrollmentTask">
<forms>
<form id="reimbursement:enrollmentForm">
.
.
</form>
</forms>
<config>
```

Any idea? Just enrollmentForm didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding this id="reimbursement:enrollmentForm"?
 Form ids identify which form will be used on perticular view.

```
 <!-- Document Library pop-up Edit Metadata form -->
         <form id="doclib-simple-metadata">

    <!-- Document Library Inline Edit form -->
         <form id="doclib-inline-edit">

  <!-- cm:folder type (existing nodes) -->
   <config evaluator="node-type" condition="cm:folder">

 <!-- Default form configuration for the cm:folder type -->
         <form>

  <!-- cm:content type (creating nodes) -->
   <config evaluator="model-type" condition="cm:content">
```

I have added few snippets from out of box **share-form-config.xml** based on which you can figure out how combination of Config and form tag's attributes decide which form to load.

In short **"condition"** attribute of Config tag decide content type/ aspect with which embeded form will be associated.

**"id"** attribute of form tag decide for perticular content type form will be used for which view.